# Login to app via multiple social networks

Tags: facebook, ios5, twitter, social-networking, flickr

I have a requirement where user can do login to the app via different social networks like fb, twitter or flickr. Once user choose any of the n/w for login, the other two accounts can be linked. Now my problem is where should I save the linked account details like auth tokens, because we need these linked account details when user does re login after logs out.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you not use a Database to store it?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How about storing the server? and getting back from the same?